# $.ajax is not a function jquery 3.x error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below jquery code snippet which sends some request to the server:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#approveButton").click(function(){
        
       $.ajax({
       method: "POST",  
       url:"/goHere",
       data:{
         month: "January",
         team: "myteam"
       }}).done(function(data){});
      });
  });
</script>
```

The `approveButton` click function is indeed working but I am getting an error like `$.ajax is not a function`. Can anyone help me with the issue? I am not even using the slim version of jquery, still I am getting the error.

Thanks!

Comment: the code as shown would not result in that error - perhaps there's something else you're doing elsewhere that is messing up what `$` is - as an interim check, try doing `$(document).ready(function ($) {`

Comment: Amazing!! It worked when I passed $ as an arguement in ready callback function. But why did it work?

Comment: not sure - probably something to do with something else you do in some code you haven't posted - I can think of many ways this could happen

Comment: Btw. You should no longer use click function but on('click', function) instead.